# Activator.CreateInstance and passing a boxed object to an invoked method

Tags: c#, reflection, activator

I have the following code ...

My Command handler:

```
public class MyHandler : IHandler
{
  // I Want to get rid of this method
  public override void ExecuteOperation(BaseOperation operation)
  {
    // This is a work-around
    this.ExecuteOperation(operation as SpecificOperation);
  }

  public override void ExecuteOperation(SpecificOperation operation)
  {
    // Do actual work here
  }
}
```

My Command handler dispatcher:

```
private dynamic FindOperationHandler(TBaseProvisioningOperation operation)
{
  ... some logic here
  return Activator.CreateInstance(handlerType, ... args here ...)
}
```

My consumer code

```
public void PerformProvisioningOperation(BaseOperation operation)
{
  // Find the correct handler for this operation
  var operationHandler = this.FindOperationHandler(operation as TBaseProvisioningOperation);

  // make it execute the operation
  // NOTE: 'operation' is SpecificOperation type, for example
  operationHandler.ExecuteOperation(operation); // <--- problem is here
}
```

The issue is that when I create an instance of my handler class with the `Activator.CreateInstance` and pass it a boxed object (i.e. as "`BaseOperation`") parameter, .NET looks for a method in the handler, which has a parameter of the base type, instead of automatically invoking the one which can handle the object if it were unboxed (i.e. explicitly cast).

Of course we have `SpecificOperation : BaseOperation`

In other words: I want when I execute `operationHandler.ExecuteOperation(operation);`, .NET to invoke `ExecuteOperation(SpecificOperation operation)` instead of `ExecuteOperation(BaseOperation operation)`, because the operation parameter is boxed (i.e. it IS `SpecificOperation` but is downcast-ed as `BaseOperation`).

How do I achieve that?

Edit:

```
public interface IHandler<TOperation> where TOperation : BaseOperation
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// TODO: Get rid of this method
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="operation">The operation to execute - boxed</param>
        void ExecuteOperation(BaseOperation operation);

        /// <summary>
        /// Executes the operation
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="operation">The operation to execute - unboxed</param>
        void ExecuteOperation(TOperation operation);
    }
```

Comment: You should avoid returning `dynamic` if the complete code is in C#.

Comment: What is the actual type being returned from `FindOperationHandler`? Also, what's `TBaseProvisioningOperation`? Are there any generics involved?

Comment: @JeroenvanLangen, I assume `dynamic` is used here to achieve Double Dispatch

Comment: I have tried to get rid of the dynamic, but was not successful. Will try again. Yes, there are generics involved, however they are only relevant to my command-finding logic (which works) so I try to leave them out from this question. The actual type behind the 'dynamic' is (something like) IHandler, with some generics parameterization.

Comment: Just use the `base` parameter type, and typecast within the implementation.

Comment: That's the thing, I don't want to cast. I want the IHandler implementation to receive a strongly-typed method parameter (which it does). However, now I am stuck with two methods (one which is the base, and the actual strongly-typed one). I want to get rid of the based one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you're using `dynamic` here to achieve Double-Dispatch, the problem is that you're casting the wrong object.

It's the `operation` variable that needs to be casted (in order to defer  overload resolution until runtime), not the `operationHandler`.

Try this instead:

```
operationHandler.ExecuteOperation(operation as dynamic);
```

And you can avoid the redundant `dynamic` definition on your `FindOperationHandler`:

```
private IHandler FindOperationHandler(TBaseProvisioningOperation operation)
{
  return Activator.CreateInstance(handlerType, ... args here ...) as IHandler;
}
```

See [Double-Dispatch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_dispatch)

Comment: You are a GOD. Thank you, `as dynamic` in the parameter solved my issue!

Answer (score 0):

You should avoid returning `dynamic` if the complete code is in C#. The `Activator.CreateInstance` is returning an `Object` not a dynamic.
Dynamics are for interop between scriptlanguages when the properties/methods aren't strongtyped.

Too bad you didn't described the `IHandler` interface, but...

I think; The problem you facing is your interface defines that your class must implement the `void ExecuteOperation(BaseOperation operation);` This way your `FindOperationHandler` should return an `IHandler`.

```
private IHandler FindOperationHandler(TBaseProvisioningOperation operation)
{
    ... some logic here
    return (IHandler)Activator.CreateInstance(handlerType, ... args here ...)
}
```

And for your handler:

```
public class MyHandler : IHandler
{

    public override void ExecuteOperation(BaseOperation operation)
    {
        var operation = (SpecificOperation)operation;
        // Do actual work here
    }
}
```

Comment: I have edited my question to include the definiton of the handler interface. Also, thanks for your answer, but my goal is to not have to cast. I want to use the strongly typed method parameter which is achieved with generics in the IHandler interface.